# What is the standard error of a binomial process with a false-positive rate

Tags: binomial-distribution, measurement-error, error-propagation

I have a question that must be common, but after searching, I can't find an explanation. Suppose we wish to estimate the percentage of people, *p*, who have a disease.  We test *n* people.  The test has known true-positive and a false-positive rates of *TP* and *FP*.  The expected number positive tests is $E[Y]=TPp+FP(1-p)$.  Solving for *p*, the estimate of *p* is $$p = \frac{(y/n)-FP}{TP-FP}$$  How do we calculate the error in the estimate of *p*?  There is uncertainty/error from the sampling of the population (binomial distribution of with *n* samples and probability *p*) and additional uncertainty/error from the test's true-positives and false-positive rates, which are also binomial distributions.

Comment: Could you clarify if $TP,FP$ are to be treated as known or unknown? You state them as known, but are concerned with the uncertainty in them later.

Comment: @user1848065 I think OP meant that any single patient not only undergoes a Bernoulli trial to determine their healthy/sick status, but also a second trial to determine whether their test flags positive, which depends on TP and FP. I don't think OP meant that the TP and FP values themselves have uncertainty

Answer (score 4):

Let $T$=TP and $F$=FP, which are known and constant. Also assume $T\neq F$.

Taking a step back, let $Y_i$ be an independent binary variable corresponding to a single patient's test result. We have
\begin{align*}
P(Y_i=1)&=Tp+F(1-p)=F+(T-F)p\\
P(Y_i=0)&=1-F-(T-F)p\\
\end{align*}
The variance (as $Y_i$ is a Bernoulli variable) is thus $$Var(Y_i)=\Big(F+(T-F)p\Big)\Big(1-F-(T-F)p\Big)$$

Now, turning our attention to $\hat{p}$, the estimator for $p$. As you say, it is:
\begin{align*}
\hat{p}&=\frac{y-F}{T-F}
\end{align*}

where we defined $y:=\frac{1}{N}\sum_i^N Y_i$, which is the overall percentage of positive test results. The variance of $\hat{p}$ is

\begin{align*}
Var(\hat{p})&=\frac{\sum_i^N Var(Y_i)}{N^2(T-F)^2}\\
&= \frac{Var(Y_i)}{N(T-F)^2}\\
&= \frac{\Big(F+(T-F)p\Big)\Big(1-F-(T-F)p\Big)}{N(T-F)^2}
\end{align*}

The standard error is the square root of the above, while substituting in our estimate $\hat{p}$:

\begin{align*}
SE(\hat{p})&=\sqrt{\frac{\Big(F+(T-F)\hat{p}\Big)\Big(1-F-(T-F)\hat{p}\Big)}{N(T-F)^2}}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{y(1-y)}{N(T-F)^2}}
\end{align*}

This expression is consistent with our intuition that the standard error is small (ie. high certainty in our estimation of the prevalence $p$) when $N$ is large, $T$ is large or $F$ is small.

---

Footnote: what if $T=F$?
Intuitively, this means the test is worthless; sick and healthy patients are just as likely to test positive, meaning the test is completely uncorrelated to the disease process. Hence there's no point trying to estimate $p$ from such a test.

Comment: Thanks, cambridgecircus for you clear and most helpful answer, which has helped me learn.

Comment: The comments on the original post raise an interesting question.  Suppose $T$ and $F$ as random variables with known probabilities, such as $T=p(Y=1|X=1)$, where $X$ is the patient's true state, disease or not.  The $Var(Y_i)$ is the variance of the sum of two (negatively) correlated terms: $Tp$ and $F(1-p)$.  The algebra simplifies nicely.  However, can we treat $T$ and $F$ as random variables when addressing the variance of $Y_i$ but treat them as parameters elsewhere in the equation for $\hat{p}$?

Comment: @GaryS no worries, if this answer has helped, please mark it as answered. Regarding your follow-on comment, yes it's possible to have $T$ and $F$ as RVs themselves. However I'm not too sure what yo mean by $Tp$ and $F(1-p)$ being negatively correlated, and the algebra simplyfing. Also I'm not sure what you mean by treating $T$,$F$ as RVs but parameters elsewhere; the point is that $\hat{p}$ will be a compound probability distribution parameterised by $T$ and $F$, which are RVs themselves.